# Are irreducible matrix algebra neccesarily simple?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In more detail, let $F$ be any field and $A$ a set of matrices, $F\cdot Id_n \subseteq A\subseteq GL_n(F)$, closed under addition and product, which is irreducible: If $\{0\}\subsetneq V \subsetneq F^n$, then $V$ is not $A$-invariant. Does it follow that the only 2-sided ideals of $A$, as an abstract $F$-algebra, are $\{0\},A$?

Comment: This is a consequence of Wedderburn theory; the answer is yes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But doesn't Weddeburn theorem require you to know a-priori that $A$ is semi-simple? Is there any reference for the claim?

Comment: Part of the Wedderburn theory is that if an algebra has a faithful irreducible representation, then it is semi-simple.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it.
Let $V=F^n, e_1,\ldots e_n$ be the standard basis of $V$. We have a morphism of $A$-modules $F:A\rightarrow V^n$ given by $a\mapsto (a\cdot e_1,\ldots ,a\cdot e_n)$, which is injective since $V$ is faithful. Now, since $A$ (as an $A$-module) embeds in the semisimple module $V^n$, $A\simeq V^k$ for some $k$. Two-sided ideals of $A$ correspond to submodules $M\le V^k$ which are invariant under $End_A(V^k)$. It enough to use $\pi_{i,j}\in End_A(V^k)$ given by $\pi_{i,j}(v_1,\ldots v_k)=(0,0,..,v_i,..,0)$, non-zero only in the $j$'th position, to see that $M\ne\{0\}$ implies $M=V^k$.